# Sorting by a field of another table referenced by a foreign key in SQLObject

Tags: python, sorting, sqlobject

Is it possible to sort results returned by SQLObject by a value of another table?

I have two tables:

```
    class Foo(SQLObject):
        bar = ForeignKey('Bar')

    class Bar(SQLObject):
        name = StringCol()
        foos = MultipleJoin('Foo')
```

I'd like to get `foo`s sorted by the `name` of a `bar` they are related to.

Doing:

```
    foos = Foo.select().orderBy(Foo.q.bar)
```

...would sort the output by `bar`'s ids, but how do I sort them by `bar`'s name?

Comment: have you tried foos = Foo.select().orderBy(Foo.q.bar.name)? I guess it would sort the output by bar's name.

Comment: @Ainab: Yep, it won't work. AttributeError: SQLObjectField instance has no attribute 'name'

Comment: The question would be easier to understand if you gave a realistic example rather than foo and bar.

Answer (score 3):

Below is the answer of a SQLObject maintainer (he has trouble posting it himself because captcha is not displayed):

Do an explicit join:

```
foos = Foo.select(Foo.q.barID==Bar.q.id, orderBy=Bar.q.name)
```

This generates a query:

```
SELECT foo.id, foo.bar_id FROM foo, bar WHERE ((foo.bar_id) = (bar.id)) ORDER BY bar.name
```

PS. I am the current maintainer of SQLObject. I don't visit stackoverflow.com; a friend of mine pointed me to the question. If you have more questions about SQLObject I invite you to the [SQLObject mailing list](http://sqlobject.org/community.html) .